# Notify parent page from child page

Tags: c#, uwp

I am building an app using UWP and I have MainPage.cs which contains a Frame control where I load different child pages. I would like to pass a listener to the child page to notify my parent page about event that happen in the child. On android I would pass a callback listener which I will have to trigger in the sub-pages so I can get notified in parentl The issue here is that pages are started Frame.Navigate(typeOf(LoginPage)) for which I cannot set a callback since login page is not a referece/object but a type class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `MainPage` is a singleton instance. In such case you could just expose this instance by creating a `static MainPage Instance` property in `MainPage` and set it in its constructor. Then you could access `MainPage` directly from any other page.

The proper solution however would be to use a MVVM framework and instead of communicating between the views directly put the communication within the view models. In MVVM you usually have a sort of *navigation service* which allows passing parameters/return values and also you can have a *event aggregator* to raise messages to which other components can subscribe. Good examples of MVVM frameworks are MvvmCross, MvvmLight and Prism. It is definitely worth learning to use and integrate them early on, because it will make your life significantly easier in terms of code maintenance in the long run.